# android tutorial pubsub don't work

Tags: ros, android-core, publish, rosjava-core, ros-groovy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I installed rosjava_core and android_core in my ros groovy pc, then i followed the tutorials and i tried the android_camera tutorial app which works fine.
Now i tried the android_tutorial_pubsub app because i must write an app which publish a string but it does't work. I followed this procedure:

> $ roscd android_core  
> $ android update project --path ./android_tutorial_pubsub/ --target android-17
> $ cd android_tutorial_pubsub  
> $ ../gradlew debug
> $ adb -d install -r ./bin/MainActivity-debug.apk  
> $ roscore &
> $ rosrun roscpp_tutorials listener

but it does't subscribe to anything. What is the issue?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/71050/android-tutorial-pubsub-don%27t-work/) by [mrpiccolo](https://answers.ros.org/users/4072/mrpiccolo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 36 on 2013-08-04

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [yigit](https://answers.ros.org/users/2389/yigit/) on 2013-08-04**:
What about rostopic list? Before running the last command (rosrun roscpp_tutorials listener), "chatter" appears there in the topics list? If so, are you sure that there aren't some kind of network issues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I resolved. There was an error in the source code, the nodeconfiguration was private, but to comunicate whit the pc must be public. thanks

---

Originally posted by [mrpiccolo](https://answers.ros.org/users/4072/mrpiccolo/) with karma: 36 on 2013-08-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0